# what's the difference between android internal storage and external-private storage?

Tags: java, android, persistence, storage

I have read the android official documentation regarding android storage.

I understand there are:

1) internal storage: which is app-private. deleted when the app is removed. cannot be accessed by user nor other apps.

2) external storage -

2.a) private: app-private. deleted when the app is removed. cannot be accessed by user nor other apps.

2.b) public: the user and other apps can access and even edit.

from the official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal):

> Saving files that are app-private
>
> If you are handling files that are not intended for other apps to use
>   (such as graphic textures or sound effects used by only your app), you
>   should use a private storage directory on the external storage by
>   calling getExternalFilesDir(). This method also takes a type argument
>   to specify the type of subdirectory (such as DIRECTORY_MOVIES). If you
>   don't need a specific media directory, pass null to receive the root
>   directory of your app's private directory.

So what is the difference between (1) and (2.a) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So what is the difference between (1) and (2.a) ?

There is no 2.a that meets your description. There is app-*specific* external storage that is removed on an uninstall, though the user and other apps can certainly get at it. Hence, it is not app-*private*.

You may wish to read some recent blog posts that I wrote that cover [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) and [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Comment: see my edited question. and here: If you are handling files that are not intended for other apps to use, you
 should use a private storage directory on the external storage

Comment: @user1065869: Here "private" simply means "not going to collide with anyone else's directory". There are no security restrictions preventing other apps, let alone the user, from accessing those files. This is in contrast to internal storage, which *is* protected from other apps and users (except on rooted devices).

Answer (score -1):

1. external storage means a space for applications and files
2. private means space for system files

Comment: and what's the difference user or application wise?